# SQL - Getting the 3rd String After a Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, database, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

so for example I have this data:

rmchat://room/kotak.com/Kotak_Debt_Brokers

I need to just get the "Kotak" from the string and show it in another column. Is there a way to get it? I have been searching online and I cannot seem to find a solution on this. Please help me.

```
STR, REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '(.*?)(\/||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1)
```

This is my current code but it's outputting the last String which is Kotak_Debt_Brokers.

Comment: `||` is wrong, in regex, use a single `|` to say "OR".

Comment: You should describe with regular words the algorithm you want to apply to the data. Because there can be any symbol after `Kotak` and no one can guess should it be in output or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '.*/([^_]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Or, alternatively,

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(STR, '.*/([^_]+).*', '\\1')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/NtJdj5/1) / [regex proof (`regexp_replace`)](https://regex101.com/r/NtJdj5/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Tried this one just now and it's still outputting the last string which is the Kotak_Debt_Brokers. I need to output only the 3rd string which is the Kotak after .com.

Comment: @eggscapethepain Sorry, it is impossible if what you posted in the question is true. For safety, try `REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '.*/([^_]+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)`, but it should be actually the same. Or, try a replace: `REGEXP_REPLACE(STR, '.*/([^_]+).*', '\\1')`

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '([^/_]+)_[^/]*$', 1, 1, 'e')
```

You can also try:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_[^/]*$', 1, 1, 'e')
```

This returns only alphanumeric characters after the hyphen

Comment: Tried this one just now and it's still outputting the last string which is the  Kotak_Debt_Brokers. I need to output only the 3rd string which is the Kotak after .com.

Comment: @eggscapethepain . . . I just made a slight modification to the expression in parenthesis.

Comment: Yes its outputting the Kotak_Debt only. I am not familiar with regex so I really don't know how to get the third string. :(

Comment: @eggscapethepain . . . It cannot return a string with an underscore, unless the underscore in the pattern (in `[^/_]`) is different from the underscore in the data.

Comment: rmchat://room/kotak.com/Kotak_Debt_Brokers

No. I don't need to get the string with an underscore. I only need the String after / and .com which is the "kotak"  after room/ and .com data.

Comment: @eggscapethepain . . . I get that.  I am saying that the pattern explicitly specifies that no underscore is in the returned string.  So if you are getting one, you might have different "underscores" in your data.